# NuGet for .NET Core on Linux

Tags: linux, nuget, .net-core

When you do `dotnet restore` .NET Core quite obviously downloads NuGet packages. But I cannot find a NuGet command line utility for .NET Core (there is one for [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29), but I'm not after *that*).

So how do you get NuGet to work from the command line with .NET Core on Linux (outside of package restore obviously. That works out of the box).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With recent .NET Core SDK releases, such as [1.0.0 RC4](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/rc4-download.md), NuGet is shipped with .NET Core. You can directly access NuGet by specifying it as a command with `dotnet`:

```
dotnet nuget
```

If the version of the .NET Core SDK does not support that you could look at downloading a [nightly build](https://www.myget.org/F/nugetbuild) of NuGet v4. There is a NuGet.CommandLine.Xplat NuGet package which supports being run on .NET Core. However, you need all its dependencies in the same folder and the NuGet package does not specify them. Downloading just the NuGet.CommandLine.Xplat NuGet package will not work directly. It will show an error about missing NuGet assemblies.

Your final option, which you said you did not want to do, is to install Mono.

Comment: The link you've given does not appear to be *nightly* build, the latest item on it seems to be about a week old.

Comment: The link does include recent builds. Did you look for pre-release builds? I can see a recent NuGet.CommandLine.Xplat pre-release NuGet packages from today (4.0.0-rtm-2304).

Answer (score 6):

The [latest dotnet core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet) includes the following commands:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet add package [package name]
dotnet remove package [package name]
dotnet pack
dotnet nuget push
dotnet nuget delete
dotnet nuget locals
```